# Is there a scheduling service in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need something like SQS that would call my api on schedule. Also I need to be able to create new "schedules"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Cloudwatch events is what you are looking for:

> > Events—An event indicates a change in your AWS environment. AWS resources can generate events when their state changes. For example, Amazon EC2 generates an event when the state of an EC2 instance changes from pending to running, and Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling generates events when it launches or terminates instances. AWS CloudTrail publishes events when you make API calls. You can generate custom application-level events and publish them to CloudWatch Events. ***You can also set up scheduled events that are generated on a periodic basis***. For a list of services that generate events, and sample events from each service, see CloudWatch Events Event Examples From Supported Services.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html